# Affected or Effected

Tags: grammar

I am writing a game and when the player gains a weakness I want to send them a message but I don't know the correct word to put of effected or affected. I know one is a noun and one is a verb but I don't understand which to use in my case.

'You were effected due to low temperatures'

or

'You were affected due to low temperatures'

Which would be the correct one?

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/affect-vs-effect/

Comment: When you looked those words up in a dictionary, what did it tell you?

Comment: @Cascabel It said one is a verb and one is a noun but I didn't understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: You should include that in your question...right now it looks like you are using us as GR.

Comment: This is one of the most common English questions that ever get asked. Your player was "affected" by the hazardous "effect" of very low temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is correct. An “effect” (noun) is what “affects” (verb) something. “Affect” and “effect” are both nouns and verbs, but “effect” is almost always used as a noun, while the noun form of “affect” is [chiefly used in psychology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect). Thus, in common parlance, “affect” is generally a verb and “effect” is generally a noun. [This may help you understand better.](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/04/30/affect-vs-effect-quick-visual-guide/)

Comment: Do you mean the second one as in the title for 'effected' or second sentence 'affected'?

Comment: @Dan The second sentence you provided.

Comment: @Dan Also, if you go to Merriam-Webster’s page for “affect,” there is an *Ask the Editor* video which succinctly explains the difference between “affect” and “effect.”